# Scripts not working below flickerplate script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope someone here is familiar with flickerplate. It's a slider plugin for your website.

The slider works great, but somehow whenever i add a new script beneath the script that loads flickerplate and it's settings, they don't work.
Unless I put them all the way down on the bottom of my file, beneath the   tag.

the issue is quite easily solved.. by putting all of my scripts above the flickerplate script. But I'm still eager to know what is causing this.

So this way it doesn't work:

```
<script>
<!--Execute flickerplate-->
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.flicker-example').flickerplate({
        auto_flick : true,
        auto_flick_delay : 8,
        block_text : true,
        dot_alignment : 'center',
        dot_navigation : true,
        flick_animation : 'transition-slide',
        flick_position : 1,
        theme : 'light'
    });
});
</script>       
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#LeftSide").hover(function(){
            $("#LeftImage1").attr("src", "images/Jesse Joey James Logo2.png");
        },function(){
            $("#LeftImage1").attr("src", "images/Jesse Joey James Logo.png");
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#RightSide").hover(function(){
            $("#RightImage1").attr("src", "images/Triple-J Productions Logo2.png");
        },function(){
            $("#RightImage1").attr("src", "images/Triple-J Productions Logo.png");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using f12, firebug, etc and see if there are any javascript errors thrown?

Comment: It looks like fickerplate script produces an error and the error blocks execution of all JS below.